# Call Laravel controller action from Job handler, with dependency injections

Tags: php, laravel

I have middleware that put task in a queue, passing $actionName and GET/POST parameters to Job constructor. This code:

```
$actionName = last(explode('@', $request->route()->getActionName()));
$arguments = $request->query->all();
$job = new HandleApiRequest($actionName, $arguments);
dispatch($job);
```

And then, in Job handler, I'd like to call Controller method with passed arguments(arguments initialized in Job constructor, don't worry about that). Here is a code:

```
$data = app()->call(ApiController::class . '@' . $this->method, $this->arguments);
```

The problem, is that I cannot use Request object(*Illuminate\Http\Request*) in called Controller and it's services. Seems like controller goes to infinite loop, and in it services it's just empty. Then I see this logs in console from worker:

```
[Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException]                                                      
  Target [App\Http\Requests\Request] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\Api\ApiController].
```

The question is, how can I properly initialize Request object in Job handler?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly you'd do that but have you tried allowing Laravel to construct the controller and handle that for you?  `$controller = \App::Make(ApiController::class); call_user_func([$controller, $this->method], $this->arguments);`?

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't solve the problem. Anyway, thanks for response :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution was to inject Request object into handler method, and fill it with data passed from middleware:

```
class HandleApiRequest extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    private $method;
    private $arguments;

    public function __construct(string $method, array $arguments)
    {
        $this->method = $method;
        $this->arguments = $arguments;


    }

    public function handle(ErrorService $error_service, Request $request)
    {
        /*
         * Fill our empty request object with arguments passed by middleware.
         * It's later will be used in controller and services.
         */
        $request->query->add($this->arguments);
        $data = app()->call(ApiController::class . '@' . $this->method);

        //use $data here
    }

}
```

Hope it will be useful for somebody, otherwise I'll delete this whole thread later.

Comment: Can you show how you injected into the handle method? Laravel docs are so lacking that they barely show anything beyond running an artisan command.

Comment: You can already see it in this example. Look at the handle function arguments: $error_service and $request with type-hints - both will be automatically resolved and injected by framework.

Comment: I'm sorry but your example shows the parameters coming into the method, not how or where (class or function example perhaps) the ErrorService or Request object are being passed into the handle() method.  This is what I am curious about.

Comment: @ShaneMit, you don't have to pass those arguments into handle method by hand. You don't event call handle method anywhere, it called automatically by the framework. Look, if you pass something with class name as type hint in any function in your Laravel application, framework already knows what to do. It will create instance of this class and inject it into method automatically. In this case ErrorService and Request. You should read more about it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container and here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers. Still, feel free to ask me anything :)

Comment: @Bushikot, don't delete the thread! :) It's still helpful.